# How to create a generic controller to prevent duplication of CRUD functions in Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an application made with node.js that has a lot of controllers that use all the same CRUD functions. I would like to create a generic controller that contient CRUD functions and takes an Entity as a parameter. I would like to implement it in all the controllers.

In this example there's an example of x.controller.js with the `GetAll` function that I would like to read from the `genericController`.
X is the Model.

```
exports.getAll = (req, res, next) => {
  const options = {
    populate: req.query.populate || null,
    populateRecursive: ['true', '1'].includes(req.query.populateRecursive)
      ? true
      : ['false', '0'].includes(req.query.populateRecursive)
      ? false
      : null
  };
  X
    .find({}, options)
    .then(documents => res.json(documents))
    .catch(err => next(err));
};
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: @RandyCasburn : My question is could you suggest a genericClass that contient this function and the call from the principal controller

Comment: Export this as a (fully implemented) class and extend your X model class with this export. inheritance 101 - right? What am I missing?

Comment: The X model changes with the source of call, so It should be a parameter, also how Can I pass (req,res,next) to the generic Controller ?

Comment: Whether the model is X or Y, both would extend this base class so they both have the same functionality.  Apparently I still don't understand your design constraints. Good luck.